# Html use default headers on all pages

Tags: html

I am looking for a simple way to get a default header on all the pages I make.

Each page has different content but uses the same header and footer throughout, also the pages rely on the scripts set in the header and footer of the page to format the content.

I have tried using frameset but the content doesn't get the scripts or style defined in the header.

Basically I want to just specify the content in the html and automatically get the html of the header and footer. (i hope this makes sense)

(this is the header of the page, sorry its messy, this is for work and i was given a site and asked to fix it)

[header.html pastebin](http://pastebin.com/JRewhuM6)

Comment: sounds like you need a master layout page. It might be helpful if you mention what HTML framework you are using otherwise its hard for people to answer

Comment: Do you have access to any serverside language? Frames are kinda 1990's

Comment: Web forms - use `master pages`. MVC - use `layout pages`. Angular - use `ng-view`

Comment: im just using standard html, css and js although it is possible to use php as well. Also im more of a beginner to web building.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65214473/how-can-i-reuse-html-code-across-several-html-files

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Include another HTML file in a HTML file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8988855/include-another-html-file-in-a-html-file)

Answer (score 0):

Like the publication Sravan commented on. 6 years ago...
One of the solutions is to use JS, you can do it by vanilla JS or by JQuery.

**I do not recommend this method.**

##### JQUERY

```
<html> 
  <head> 
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script> 
        $(function(){
          $(".header").load("other.html"); 
        });
    </script> 
  </head> 

  <body> 
     <div class="header"></div>
  </body> 
</html>
```

##### Vanilla JS

```html
<!-- Random file.hml -->
<html> 
  <body> 
     <script src="header.js"></script>
  </body> 
</html>
```

```js
/*header.js*/
fetch('./header.html').then(res => {
    document.write(res);
});
```

### Why don't I recommend this method?

The wonderful world of CORS is present here. So it is very likely that when you try to call the file, it will not allow you to pick up the file. (And most likely that's why it appeared empty before).
In a localhost environment it is very likely that CORS, in a server environment it is possible that it will work.

### What do you recommend then?

Generally a server apart from having HTML, CSS and JS. It has PHP (and from what you say that it is for a one-page support, it is very likely to be so).
PHP allows to include in a much simpler way what you are trying to do.

#### PHP

```
<html> 
  <body> 
     <?php
       include_once('header.php');       
     ?>
  </body> 
</html>
```

To change the file from an html to a PHP file, just change the file extension to `.php`

#### EDIT - EXPLANATION

I transcribe what I have put in comments:

In general, HTML is not intended for you to have more than one file, since the structure of the language was intended (and has not been modified) for the first static pages before dynamic pages became more popular (possibly in the early 1995's).

Then came Javascript which allowed to collect the content of more files, but due to the evolution of browsers. CORS became much stricter and this functionality cannot be used without a server (either local as with XAMPP or remote with a hosting).

Here comes PHP, PHP is one of the most used languages to maintain a web server (I just hope that Python fans don't come and say that PHP is dead).
Both XAMPP and the vast majority of web hosting, are PHP (hence I put the answer in PHP).

PD: Nobody thinks about the flash... (nobody thinks about the children, web version)

Comment: I want to revive this question because I have the exact same question myself. I don't find most of the answers sufficient so I decided to split up my repuation.

Comment: Well, it's really a question without much specification. In what environment are you having the problem?
Localhost? Server?
As I say in the answer. It is much easier in a server environment.
If you use a framework it is also much easier than pure JS.

Comment: Just in general. (Which is the point)

Comment: Well, in a general environment... The HTML base is intended for the first static pages that existed, so it was not intended to have many files.
On the other hand, with the navigation security updates. The browsers have begun to be much more strict with the CORS (Hence the 1st point of the answer)

Comment: So you are going to need a web server if at all possible. Either in a local (XAMPP) or remote (Hosting) environment.
Xampp uses PHP and in remote PHP is part of 80% (maybe more) of web servers. Add this explanation in response

Answer (score 0):

To achieve a consistent header and footer on all the pages you create, while still having the styles and scripts applied to the content, you can use a server-side templating system. This allows you to define common header and footer templates and include them in your individual pages. Here's a simplified example of how you can do this:

1. Create header and footer templates in separate HTML files, for example:
   header.html:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Your Website</title>
  <!-- Include your common stylesheets and scripts here -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
  <script src="common.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <header>
    <!-- Your header content goes here -->
    <h1>Your Website Header</h1>
  </header>
```

footer.html:

```html
  <footer>
    <!-- Your footer content goes here -->
    <p>&copy; 2023 Your Website</p>
  </footer>
</body>
</html>
```

2. Create individual pages (e.g., page1.html, page2.html, etc.) with your specific content. Include placeholders for the header and footer templates:
   page1.html:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Page 1</title>
</head>
<body>
  <!-- Include the header template -->
  <div id="header-placeholder"></div>

  <!-- Your specific page content goes here -->
  <h1>Welcome to Page 1</h1>
  <p>This is the content of Page 1.</p>

  <!-- Include the footer template -->
  <div id="footer-placeholder"></div>

  <!-- Your page-specific scripts go here -->
  <script src="page1.js"></script>

  <!-- Include JavaScript to load header and footer -->
  <script src="loadHeaderFooter.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Similarly create for page 2.

3. Create a JavaScript file (e.g., loadHeaderFooter.js) to load the header and footer templates dynamically:

```js
// Function to load the header and footer templates
function loadHeaderAndFooter() {
  // Load header template
  fetch('header.html')
    .then(response => response.text())
    .then(data => {
      document.getElementById('header-placeholder').innerHTML = data;
    });

  // Load footer template
  fetch('footer.html')
    .then(response => response.text())
    .then(data => {
      document.getElementById('footer-placeholder').innerHTML = data;
    });
}

// Call the function to load header and footer
loadHeaderAndFooter();
```

4. Customize your individual pages with specific content and scripts.

Comment: Code only answers are not good.

Comment: Hi @BlueRobin, the code is running fine. What was the fault in this, please address?

Comment: I have added another line of code to get on top i.e., header.

Comment: Please explain your method outside of the code block. Otherwise, it's of no use.

Comment: @BlueRobin Sure, here is the complete brief explanation. Kindly go through this.

Answer (score 0):

For building static sites in a modern component driven way it makes sense to use static site generators like [Hugo](https://gohugo.io) or [Jekyll](https://jekyllrb.com).

With static site generators you have the ability to use components in your HTML, which then replaced with the html they contain. The tool simply replaces the bits you define when generating the production site.

Another advantage of using this methods over the proposed php backend solution is that the hosting requirements stay exactly the same just like if you would use just html/css/js.

Here is an example how your layout could look like.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    {{ partial "head.html" . }}
    <body>
        <!-- header -->
        {{ partial "header.html" . }}
        <!-- /header -->

        <!-- main -->
        <main>
            {{ block "main" . }}{{ end }}
        </main>
        <!-- /main -->

        <!-- footer -->
        {{ partial "footer.html" . }}
        <!-- /footer -->
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -4):

You can try something like this. You can save the data in a html file and load the data into other using the jquery.
You can use the jquery methods to load the data into header and footer, you may use a single html or even two files.

```html
<html> 
  <head> 
    <script src="jquery.js"></script> 
    <script> 
     $(function(){
       $(".header").load("other.html"); 
     });
    </script> 
  </head> 

  <body> 
     <div class="header"></div>
  </body> 
</html>
```

Other.html

```
This is header data.
```

http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/html-import/ Check this link, you may get an answer.

Comment: i have tried this and only got a blank page. I have updated my question to include the header html file

Comment: I have added a link, go through it, you may get an answer.