# How can I reuse HTML code across several HTML files

Tags: html, dom, bootstrap-4

hope all are doing well.

I've tried many solutions across the internet, but not getting the result I want.

I am writing bootstrap code in html files. I am using `adminlte.io` template for that purpose.

I just have to change the body text of that dashboard and all other things will remain same across the webpages. How can I RE-USE both before and after code.

I am not using php, or anyother framework just simple html file or I may use JS files if that's necessary for the accurate results.... Thank You in advance!

**Re-usable upper code:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <title>AB1 Dashboard</title>
  <!-- Tell the browser to be responsive to screen width -->
  <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no" name="viewport">
  <!-- Bootstrap 3.3.7 -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <!-- Font Awesome -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <!-- Ionicons -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/Ionicons/css/ionicons.min.css">
  <!-- Theme style -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="dist/css/AdminLTE.min.css">
  <!-- AdminLTE Skins. Choose a skin from the css/skins
       folder instead of downloading all of them to reduce the load. -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="dist/css/skins/_all-skins.min.css">
  <!-- Morris chart -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/morris.js/morris.css">
  <!-- jvectormap -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/jvectormap/jquery-jvectormap.css">
  <!-- Date Picker -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/bootstrap-datepicker/dist/css/bootstrap-datepicker.min.css">
  <!-- Daterange picker -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/bootstrap-daterangepicker/daterangepicker.css">
  <!-- bootstrap wysihtml5 - text editor -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="plugins/bootstrap-wysihtml5/bootstrap3-wysihtml5.min.css">

  <!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
  <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
  <!--[if lt IE 9]>
  <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.3/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
  <![endif]-->

  <!-- Google Font -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro:300,400,600,700,300italic,400italic,600italic">
</head>
<body class="hold-transition skin-blue sidebar-mini">
<div class="wrapper">

  <header class="main-header">
    <!-- Logo -->
    <a href="#" class="logo">
      <!-- mini logo for sidebar mini 50x50 pixels -->
      <span class="logo-mini"><b>WOW</b></span>
      <!-- logo for regular state and mobile devices -->
      <span class="logo-lg"><b>WOW</b> | Admin panel</span>
    </a>
    <!-- Header Navbar: style can be found in header.less -->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-static-top">
      <!-- Sidebar toggle button-->
      <a href="#" class="sidebar-toggle" data-toggle="push-menu" role="button">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
      </a>

      <div class="navbar-custom-menu">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          
          <!-- User Account: style can be found in dropdown.less -->
          <li class="dropdown user user-menu">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
              <img src="dist/img/user2-160x160.jpg" class="user-image" alt="User Image">
              <span class="hidden-xs">Alexander Pierce</span>
            </a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <!-- User image -->
              <li class="user-header">
                <img src="dist/img/user2-160x160.jpg" class="img-circle" alt="User Image">

                <p>
                  Alexander Pierce - Administrator
                  <small>Member since Nov. 2020</small>
                </p>
              </li>
              <!-- Menu Footer-->
              <li class="user-footer">
                <div class="pull-left">
                  <a href="#" class="btn btn-default btn-flat">Profile</a>
                </div>
                <div class="pull-right">
                  <a href="#" class="btn btn-default btn-flat">Sign out</a>
                </div>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </header>
  <!-- Left side column. contains the logo and sidebar -->
  <aside class="main-sidebar">
    <!-- sidebar: style can be found in sidebar.less -->
    <section class="sidebar">
      <!-- Sidebar user panel -->
      <div class="user-panel">
        <div class="pull-left image">
          <img src="dist/img/user2-160x160.jpg" class="img-circle" alt="User Image">
        </div>
        <div class="pull-left info">
          <p>Admin user</p>
          <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-circle text-success"></i> Online</a>
        </div>
      </div>
     
      <!-- sidebar menu: : style can be found in sidebar.less -->
      <ul class="sidebar-menu" data-widget="tree">
        <li class="header">MAIN NAVIGATION</li>
        <li class="active treeview">
          <a href="#">
            <i class="fa fa-dashboard"></i> <span>Dashboard</span>
            <span class="pull-right-container">
              <i class="fa fa-angle-left pull-right"></i>
            </span>
          </a>
          <ul class="treeview-menu">
            <li class="active"><a href="index.html"><i class="fa fa-circle-o"></i>User dashboard</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-user"></i> <span>Users</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-map-marker"></i> <span>Hunt</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-exclamation-circle"></i> <span>Challenge</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-briefcase"></i> <span>Corporate request</span></a></li>
        </ul>
    </section>
    <!-- /.sidebar -->
  </aside>
```

**""HERE I WANT TO USE DIFFERENT CODE IN DIFFERENT FILES""**

**Re-usable lower code:**

```
  <!-- /.content-wrapper -->
  <footer class="main-footer">
    <div class="pull-right hidden-xs">
      <b>Version</b> 2.4.0
    </div>
    <strong>Copyright &copy; 2020 <a href="#">WOW.</a></strong> All rights
    reserved.
  </footer>
</div>
<!-- ./wrapper -->

<!-- jQuery 3 -->
<script src="bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- jQuery UI 1.11.4 -->
<script src="bower_components/jquery-ui/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<!-- Resolve conflict in jQuery UI tooltip with Bootstrap tooltip -->
<script>
  $.widget.bridge('uibutton', $.ui.button);
</script>
<!-- Bootstrap 3.3.7 -->
<script src="bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<!-- Morris.js charts -->
<script src="bower_components/raphael/raphael.min.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/morris.js/morris.min.js"></script>
<!-- Sparkline -->
<script src="bower_components/jquery-sparkline/dist/jquery.sparkline.min.js"></script>
<!-- jvectormap -->
<script src="plugins/jvectormap/jquery-jvectormap-1.2.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="plugins/jvectormap/jquery-jvectormap-world-mill-en.js"></script>
<!-- jQuery Knob Chart -->
<script src="bower_components/jquery-knob/dist/jquery.knob.min.js"></script>
<!-- daterangepicker -->
<script src="bower_components/moment/min/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/bootstrap-daterangepicker/daterangepicker.js"></script>
<!-- datepicker -->
<script src="bower_components/bootstrap-datepicker/dist/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>
<!-- Bootstrap WYSIHTML5 -->
<script src="plugins/bootstrap-wysihtml5/bootstrap3-wysihtml5.all.min.js"></script>
<!-- Slimscroll -->
<script src="bower_components/jquery-slimscroll/jquery.slimscroll.min.js"></script>
<!-- FastClick -->
<script src="bower_components/fastclick/lib/fastclick.js"></script>
<!-- AdminLTE App -->
<script src="dist/js/adminlte.min.js"></script>
<!-- AdminLTE dashboard demo (This is only for demo purposes) -->
<script src="dist/js/pages/dashboard.js"></script>
<!-- AdminLTE for demo purposes -->
<script src="dist/js/demo.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Thank You for your response.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Include another HTML file in a HTML file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8988855/include-another-html-file-in-a-html-file)

Answer (score 3):

There are three places you can do this:

## When you build the site, before/during deployment.

This is a step where you take the source code you've written (along with any data you want to pull from, for example, a database) and convert it to code (and content) suitable to be copied to your server and then sent to browsers.

You can use any programming language you like for this. Generally you would use a template library and inject the content in it from a series of source files.

There are lots of [static site generators](https://www.linode.com/docs/guides/how-to-choose-static-site-generator/) which are designed to do this. Jamstack has [a longer list](https://jamstack.org/generators/) (albeit with less explanation).

## On the server

You've rejected PHP, but it or another server side language are common choices for this sort of problem, be it with a simple set of [includes](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.include.php), something slightly smarter with [templates](https://www.slant.co/topics/2866/%7Ebest-php-template-languages) or a full on big [CMS](https://www.cloudways.com/blog/best-php-cms/).

## On the client

Pulling content over [HTTP with client-side JS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) and then injecting it [into the page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Client-side_web_APIs/Manipulating_documents) is a fairly simple option, but the least friendly to search engines and most likely to break due to client issues (like network timeouts for individual files or ad-blockers).

More complex systems would use tools like [React](https://reactjs.org/) but the best of those are backed by server-side rendering (e.g. via [Next.js](https://nextjs.org/)) or build-time generated static files (e.g. via [Gatsby](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/)). That is to say you use option 1 or option 2 and then add client-side to enhance the UX and performance.