# How to load a link in an iframe in the whole browsertab?

Tags: html, css, iframe, header

I want to put my header in an iframe-element so that I can change the headers of all subpages of my website in one css. But when I click on a link in the header, the new page loads only in the iframe element. Is there any way to make the new page load in the whole browsertab rather than in the iframe?

Answer (score -1):

The [link target](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a#attr-target) determines which viewport a link opens in. To open in the parent window use `_parent`.

```
<a href="page2.html" target="_parent"> ... </a>
```

That said, using iframes to include common content is a really ugly approach to the problem with accessibility and SEO implications. I'd strongly suggest you consider using a Static Site Generator or one of the other options in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65214690/19068) instead.

Answer (score -2):

You can link a css file in the `head` part of your html code like so:

```
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="your-header-styles.css">
</head>
```

So you don't have to use iframes.

Comment: That could change the way the header looks, but it couldn't change the content of the header.

Answer (score -2):

You can't access or control the parent page from within an iframe.

If you really wanna do it the old-school way, you can use a `frameset`. But this isn't supported anymore in HTML5.

Comment: That simply isn't true. Navigation via iframes works exactly the same way that it does via framesets.