# Is ther a way to use JS to automaticly populate nav-links?

Tags: javascript, html

So I am still fairly early in my BED-Studies, and would apreciate any sugestions to be more code hevy than smart and eficient, this way i can learn.

Case:
I am creating a website that displays how the studies evolves my skills. And like any other page, it needs a nav-bar but it can get a little time consuming to retype every relevant link.

I have tried to google the question, but as far as i can find ther is a resounding "nope!", but then again, somthimes i com across people using a "file" function but i cant seem to find this function in jquery or js.

And thus back to my question: is ther a way to make JavaScript "see" the files in a location without hard-coding them in?

my folder structure is likethis:

```
/school: 
./index.html
./css
./js
./programingFoundation:
  ./pfdindex.html
  ./module1
  ./module2
  ./...
./frontEndTech:
  ./fetIndex.html
  ./module1
  ./module2
  ,/..
```

Edit:
my attempt at navigation (mainNav.js):

```
function innsertMainNav() {
    const mainNavTitles = [
        { button: 'Home', url: '/index.html', active: true },
        { button: 'JS Basic', url: '/programmingFoundations/pfindex.html', active: true },
        { button: 'Frontend', url: '/forntEndTechnologies/fetindex.html', active: true },
        { button: 'OOP', url: './programmingWithObjects/pwoindex.html', active: true },
        { button: 'Project Methodology', url: '/projectMethodology/pmindex.html', active: false },
        { button: 'Semester Project', url: '/semesterProject/smindex.html', active: false },
        { button: 'JS Servers', url: '/javaScriptServers/jssindex.html', active: false },
        { button: 'dataBases', url: '/databases/dbindex.html', active: false },
        { button: 'Rest Api', url: '/restApi/raindex.html', active: false },
        { button: 'Servers', url: '/serverDeployment/sdindex.html', active: false },
        { button: 'Exam', url: '/examProject/epindex.html', active: false }
    ];

    //insert header
    $('head').after('<header class="container-md bg-light"></header>');
    // add title and logo line
    $('header').append(`<div class="row"><h1>${document.title}</h1></div>`);
    
    // add Navigation 
    $('header').append('<nav id="mainNav" class="row">\
    <div id="outerDiv" class="container-fluid">\
        <button\
            class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse"\
            data-bs-target="#collapsing" aria-controls="collapsing"\
            aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Togglenavigation">\
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>\
        </button>\
    <div id="collapsing" class="collapse navbar-collapse">\
        <ul id="mainNavList" class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0"></ul>\
    </div></div></nav>');

    // Populate main NAV
    for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        if (mainNavTitles[i].active) {
            $('ul#mainNavList').append(`<li>\
            <a class="col" href="..${mainNavTitles[i].url}">\
            ${mainNavTitles[i].button}\
            </a></li>`);
        }
        else {
            break;
        }
    }

    $('#mainNav').addClass('navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light');
    $('nav a').addClass('nav-link');
}
```

Comment: I think you would need a software specifically designed for this need, that runs in the background and every time a folder changes, it will replace the code of your page with the new URI;
Thogh I would suggest, to simply rename the new files with the name written on the code of the page, instead of rewrite the page itself everytime.

Comment: "And thus back to my question: is ther a way to make JavaScript "see" the files in a location without hard-coding them in?" — The browser has no way to know what URLs are available on the server unless the server provides a custom API for custom JS running in the browser.

Comment: Relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65214473/how-can-i-reuse-html-code-across-several-html-files

Comment: Thank you @Quentin. This is what my conclusion has become to. Tho we haven't covered serverside and rest API's yet, and therefore i refrain form looking into those methods yet. 
I have made a solution that almost work, just need to figure out how to solve the links issues. As of now, the link to "Frontend" gives a 404 on the live-server, but not on the development-server in VS-Code.

Answer (score 0):

If you're only using HTML and vanilla JS, you could do it like this.

First, create a javascript file, and include it in every main html file you use on your website (for example, index.html. contact.html, portfolio.html, etc).

Let's call this file `helpers.js`.

Its contents would be something like this.

```
// Let's see if the HTML which is using helpers.js has its own navigation
var navigation = document.querySelectorAll("nav");
if(!navigation.length) {
    var navigation = document.createElement("nav");
} else {
    navigation = navigation[0];
}

// We'll make a centralized list of main links - the ones we want to see in the navigation
var linkList = {
  "home":"index.html",
  "portfolio":"portfolio.html",
  "about me":"about.html",
  "contact me":"contact.html"
};

// The function is here to help us populate the navigation with our links
function fillNavigation(elem, source) {
    elem.innerHTML = "";
    for(let description in source) {
        let content  = '<a href="' + source[description] + '">' + description + '</a>';
    elem.innerHTML += content;
  }
}

// We call the function, and let it work for us
fillNavigation(navigation,linkList);
```

One advantage of this is that you have one place where you change your main links list - you wouldn't have to visit each and every page of your site in order to make changes to your navigation. The `helpers.js` will do this for you.

A running example ([JS fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/dt30nwso/), in case you want to play around with this)

```js
var navigation = document.querySelectorAll("nav");
if(!navigation.length) {
    var navigation = document.createElement("nav");
} else {
    navigation = navigation[0];
}

var linkList = {
  "home":"index.html",
  "portfolio":"portfolio.html",
  "about me":"about.html",
  "contact me":"contact.html"
};

function fillNavigation(elem, source) {
    elem.innerHTML = "";
    for(let description in source) {
        let content  = '<a href="' + source[description] + '">' + description + '</a>';
    elem.innerHTML += content;
  }
}

// The timeout is here for illustrative purposes only
setTimeout(function() {
    fillNavigation(navigation,linkList);
},2000);
```

```css
nav {
  padding: 5px;
  width: calc(100% - 10px);
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #333;
  color: #fff;
}
nav a {
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 3px;
}
nav a:hover {
  color: red;
  transition: 0.5s;
}
```

```html
<nav>ok</nav>
<p>
    lorem ipsum
    sit dolor amet
    etc lupus in fabula
    homo homini lupus est
    similis simili gaudet
    bellum omnia contra omni
</p>
<hr>
<p>
    some other stuff
</p>
```

---

**EDIT** For cases where you have multi-level menus, you could use something like this. As in the first example, a fiddle [is available here](https://jsfiddle.net/toyvc285/)

```js
var navigation = document.querySelectorAll("nav");
if(!navigation.length) {
    var navigation = document.createElement("nav");
} else {
    navigation = navigation[0];
}

var linkList = {
    "home":"index.html",
    "portfolio":"portfolio.html",
    "about me":"about.html",
    "contact me":"contact.html",
    "modules":{
        "module1": {
            "lorem":"lorem.html",
            "ipsum":"ipsum.html"
        },
        "module2": {
            "foo":"foo.html",
            "bar":"bar.html"
        }
    }
};

function isObject(obj) {
  return typeof obj === 'object';
}

function renderLinks(source,flagClose) {
    let txt = "";
    for(let description in source) {
        if(isObject(source[description])) {
      txt += '<li class="parent">' + description + '<ul class="sublevel none">';
      txt += renderLinks(source[description],description);
        } else {
            let addition = flagClose ? (flagClose.trim() + '/') : ''
            txt += '<li><a href="' + addition + source[description] + '">' + description + '</a></li>';
        }
    }

  if(flagClose) {
    txt += '</ul></li>';
  }

  return txt;
}

function fillNavigation(elem, source) {
    elem.innerHTML = "";
  elem.innerHTML += renderLinks(source);
  
  // show on hover
  $("li.parent").mouseenter(function() {
    $(this).find("> ul.sublevel").removeClass("none");
  });
  
  $("li.parent").mouseleave(function() {
    $(this).find("> ul.sublevel").addClass("none");
  });
}

fillNavigation(navigation,linkList);
```

```css
.none {
  display: none !important;
}
nav {
  padding: 5px;
  width: calc(100% - 10px);
  text-align: left;
  background-color: #333;
  color: #fff;
}
nav a {
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 3px;
}
nav a:hover {
  color: red;
  transition: 0.5s;
}
li {
  list-style: none;
}
li.parent {
 position: relative;
 padding-right: 10px;
 padding-left: 5px;
}
li.parent * {
  display: block;
}
ul.sublevel {
  position: absolute;
  top: -1px; /* because of the border */
  left: 100%;
  background-color: #333;
  margin-top: 0px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  min-width: 100px;
  border: 1px solid #aaa;
  text-align: left;
}
li.parent, ul.sublevel {
  cursor: pointer;
}
nav li {
 display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav>ok</nav>
<p>lorem ipsum sit dolor amet etc lupus in fabula homo homini lupus est similis simili gaudet bellum omnia contra omni </p>
<hr>
<p>some other stuff</p>
```

You will notice a few differences from the first case (one-level menu):

- the original `linkList` has been modified, in order to show the case when there's a multi-level menu (modules/module1/link1.html, modules/module1/link2.html, etc)
- the function `fillNavigation` has been changed, as well - it now contains a call to a new function, `renderLinks`, which creates all the `innerHTML`
- `renderLinks` is a recursive function, which makes it handy for cases where you decide to change the depth of your navigation. Please note that it has been tested on one and two-level menus. It should work for more levels than that, but you would have to adjust the CSS accordingly (or change the function a bit, so that you may have specific CSS classes, connected with a specific level)
- the function `renderLinks` relies on a helper function, `isObject`. The purpose of this function is to test whether the item we're currently processing is actually a sub-menu. Since we control the original `linkList` and its structure, we can do it as shown in the code. For more complex cases (for example, where we have no, or little control on how the link list is formed, this solution would most likely be lacking)
- `hover` effect and showing of sub-level menus is handled via jQuery. There is no special reason for this, other than that I found it simpler to achieve (less to type)
- since we can have more than one menu element with children, `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` target only the first sub-level within the one we're hovering on. This also lets us travel (visually) along the hovered route, without closing the original top-level menu item which contains the one's we're currently traversing

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion! 
As I understand your example, I basically have to make all the links have roughly the same link path, but dependent on the site they would reference a different folder structure. 

ie. 
<a href='../#/module1/index.html'>Module 1</a> 
<a href='../#/module2/index.html'>Module 2</a> 

to generally link to the first page in a subfolder

Comment: Sure, that's the general idea. I've updated the code for the cases where you have a multi-level menu - start from part which has this text `For cases where you have multi-level menus`, and read on. Hope this works for what you had in mind.

Comment: nice, thank you. 
Does the `renderLinks` also guarantee correct link path? 

i made an attempt based on your first example, but i found the links to apparently not path correctly. and can't seem to find the `.html` files for some paths.

Comment: You're right - I have accidentally ommitted the most important part - the parent directory to the path. I've edited the answer and the fiddle link. The edited answer now contains the logic for the immediate parent directory. Let me know if you need the entire path (for example `module/module1/foo.html`), and I'll edit the answer with that logic.

Answer (score 0):

The question here seems to be, how do I read a local filesystem from a web browser. Browsers have a [FileAPI](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File_API) but it does not offer the ability to pass a list of the files and folders on the local filesystem without user input.

Comment: Thank you! That's true,  some times it's hard to phrase the question in a second language.