# How to prevent refresh when using HTML iframe

Tags: html, iframe

Let's say I have a piece of code below:

```
    <h1><h1>

    <div class = "content"> // this iframe is not occupy the overall page
       <iframe src = "/fileB.html"></iframe>
    </div>
```

right now, inside the , page from fileB is shown.

but in fileB, I have:

```
    <a href = 'fileC.html'></a>
```

Normally, when I click , the content  will be transformed from fileB to C, but after I click the refresh button of the browser, the div change back to fileB. So, How can I make the page stay in fileC when I click the refresh button.

Thanks:)

I want somebody can show me the code that I have to put and make it clear which JS file is for which HTML file.

Comment: This sounds like an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) where you think iframes are the solution to your problem and are not trying to work around their problems. Likely you should use something else (such as a static site generator) to [reuse code (such as menus) across pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65214473/how-can-i-reuse-html-code-across-several-html-files).

Answer (score 0):

maybe like this

fileB.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>File B</title>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>File B</h1>
  <div class="content">
    <a href="fileC.html?source=fileB">Go to File C</a>
  </div>

  <script>
    // Check if the sourcePage value is stored in localStorage
    const sourcePage = localStorage.getItem('sourcePage');
    if (sourcePage && sourcePage === 'fileB') {
      // Redirect to fileC.html
      window.location.href = 'fileC.html';
    }
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

fileC.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>File C</title>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>File C</h1>
  <div class="content">
    <p>This is File C.</p>
  </div>

  <script>
    // Get the URL parameters
    const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
    const sourcePage = urlParams.get('source');

    // Store the sourcePage value in localStorage
    localStorage.setItem('sourcePage', sourcePage);
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

user in fileB.html after that click Go To File C
then user redirect to fileC.html then user when refresh still in page fileC.html , you can modified what you want it